# Mandar correo desde mi aplicacion c#

Tags: c#

Tengo este metodo para mandar correo desde mi aplicacion el problema que tiene es que solo manda los correos si estoy dentro de un servidor que tiene permisos en la SMTP que me dieron, hay algun modo de agregar la direccion del servidor a este metodo para que todas las personas puedan mandar correo sin necesidad estar dentro del servidor.

```
            String userName = "Correo";         
            String password = "";
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("detinatario"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
            msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
            msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "SMTP";
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: a que llamas "estor dentro de un servidor " ? te refieres a que debes tener una cuenta

Comment: cual es el servicio de smtp que usas? alli se lee Office 365, peor no veo que definas cual es el Host

Comment: Este es el SMTP 'smtp.cj.mx.conti.de' pero ese solo lo pueden usar direcciones IP establecidas una de ellas es la de mi Servidor de Windows Server, cuando abro la aplicacion dentro del sevidor se pueden enviar los correos pero si la abro en otra computadora no se puede

Comment: cuando lo ejecutas desde la "otra computadora" puede resolver ese smtp si realizas un ping ? porque sino resuelve la ip quiere decir que no tiene conexion al servidor de smtp, deberias darle acceso, si es posible

Comment: Es lo que decia que solo algunas IP tiene acceso por eso busco alguna forma de agregar la IP del servidor que si tiene acceso al metodo que puse

Answer (score 0):

tengo estas lineas de codigo y en mi caso funcionan correctamenta para el proposito de envio de correos con Outlook.

```
            SmtpClient smtpserver = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            smtpserver.Port = 25;
            smtpserver.Host = "MI SMTP";
            mail.From = new MailAddress("correoenvia@correo.com", "Correo");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.To.Add("correodestino@correo.com");
            mail.CC.Add("correocopia@correo.com");
            mail.Subject = "Informació de correo";
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            mail.Body = "cuerpo del correo";
            smtpserver.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Este fragmento de código debería servirte:

```
        SmtpClient smtpserver = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        smtpserver.Port = 25;
        smtpserver.Host = "ip de tu servidor de correo";
        mail.From = new MailAddress("correoenvia@correo.com", "Correo");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.To.Add("correodestino@correo.com");
        mail.CC.Add("correocopia@correo.com");
        mail.Subject = "Asunto del correo";
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        mail.Body = "Mensaje de correo de prueba";
        smtpserver.Send(mail);
```